# Does Azure site recovery support vmware vsphere 5.0

Tags: azure, vmware, vsphere

Just reading the document here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure

It does not mention support for vsphere 5.0, does ASR support vsphere 5.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

The supported versions are listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure-classic). Based on the information below taken from that page then vSphere 5.0 is not supported.

> You need one or more vMware vSphere ESX/ESXi hypervisors managing your VMware virtual machines, running ESX/ESXi version 6.0, 5.5 or 5.1 with the latest updates.